# NextJS dynamically created Image for opengraph tags not working in production

Tags: next.js, facebook-opengraph, next.js13, nextjs-image, share-open-graph

I'm working on a Next.js project where I need to dynamically generate Open Graph images. My implementation works locally, but I'm facing issues when deploying to production on Vercel and Netlify.

**Local Environment:**

- The dynamic image generation works perfectly. Here's the working code: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/HemendraKhatik/dynamic-image-example-nextjs).

#### **Issues in Production:**

**Vercel Deployment:**

- Deployed at: [Vercel App Link](https://dynamic-image-example-nextjs.vercel.app/share/hemendra).
- Issue: If you copy the image link and open it in a new tab then it requires authentication to be viewed, which shouldn't be the case.

[image: Vercel Issue]

**Netlify Deployment:**

- Deployed at: [Netlify App Link](https://nextjs-dynamic-image.netlify.app/share/hemedra).
- Issue: The image URL is pointing to `localhost` instead of the production URL.

[image: Netlify Issue]

**Questions:**

- How can I fix the authentication issue for the dynamically generated image on Vercel?
- Why is the image URL pointing to `localhost` on Netlify, and how can I correct it to use the production URL?

Any insights or suggestions to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Reference: I followed the [Vercel Documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/functions/edge-functions/og-image-generation) for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

- Why is the image URL pointing to localhost on Netlify, and how can I correct it to use the production URL?

You should be able to use `metadataBaseUrl` in your `metadata` object. You could use it this way, in example for Vercel deployments:

```js
metadataBase: process.env.VERCEL_URL
    ? new URL(`https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`)
    : new URL(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`),
```

Same would apply for a different env variable or deployment service.

Now, regarding:

- How can I fix the authentication issue for the dynamically generated image on Vercel?

It exactly happens the same to me. I found this issue in github too: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50546#discussioncomment-8052317

EDIT: I fixed it using a hardcoded `metadataBase` instead of the autogenerated `VERCEL_URL`, which uses the deploy link instead of my own domain (which anyways should be public, but idk)

EDIT2: Ok, this was the issue, I had it enabled by default for the new project this config:

[image: config]

which asks for auth for every domain except production ones and it seems somehow Vercel doesnt take autogenerated URL as a production link even though it is.